# Displaying MySQL data in PHP Table Not working

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

Currently I'm creating just a simple website that I'm fooling around with. Users can add movies to watch, and then can view them later on. What my current problem is, is this.

[image]

Sorry for the large image. As you can see its displaying the first result correctly, but the second result gets all skrewy and displays at the top of the screen. My code for displaying the data is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movies`");

echo "
<table id=\"allTable\" align=\"center\" border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"4\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Movie</th>
<th>Genre</th></tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['genre'] . "</td";
    echo "</tr><br />";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT** Fixed the problem right after I created this. Removed  from while loop and put it under. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

`echo "</table>";` should be moved outside of your `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['genre'] . "</td";
                echo "</tr><br />";

            }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: True... Although you should consider looking at http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php